# PyGame: Unable to open file

Tags: python, pygame, python-3.4

I'm trying some basic examples from the [Making Games with Python & Pygame](https://inventwithpython.com/makinggames.pdf) book, but I'm facing a weird problem. Here is the example source:

```
import pygame, time

soundObj = pygame.mixer.Sound('beep.wav')
soundObj.play()
time.sleep(1) # wait and let the sound play for 1 second
soundObj.stop()
```

This source produces the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/Thiago/PycharmProjects/PyGame/Sound/app.py", line 3, in
>   
>       soundObj = pygame.mixer.Sound('beep.wav') pygame.error: Unable to open file 'beep.wav'

The *beep.wav* file is properly saved on the same folder of my Python script. I've tried the `os.listdir()` command and it returns the wav file. Is there any issue, known bug or am I doing something wrong?

Here is my environment:

- Windows 10 64 bits
- Python 3.4
- Pygame 1.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to initialize the module or all of the pygame first.
There is an pygame_init() initializer that is going to help you with that.
You can find it [here](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pygame.html#pygame.init)

Comment: It worked! I've added the `pygame.init()` and the `pygame.display.set_mode()`. Including the `pygame.init()` removes the error but doesn't play the sound. Adding the `pygame.display.set_mode()` produces the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem adding the `pygame.init()` to initialize the Pygame and `pygame.display.set_mode()` to create the window.

```
import pygame, time

pygame.init() # initialize the pygame
soundObj = pygame.mixer.Sound('beep.wav')
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300)) # create the game window
soundObj.play()
time.sleep(1) # wait and let the sound play for 1 second
soundObj.stop()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
brew install libogg
brew install libvorbis
brew install sdl_mixer --with-libvorbis
brew reinstall sdl_mixer --with-libvorbis
```

this function for me :D

Comment: so sorry, my mistake :(